# check in document from sharepoint after edit

Tags: vba, sharepoint, ms-word

In my word vba I open a file from sharepoint with this code

```
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(path)
```

Then I start editing the file.

After all I save it back to sharepoint with this code

```
oDoc.Save
oDoc.Close
oWord.Quit
```

The problem now is that the document is still "checked out". How can i programatically check it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this wasn't very difficult. I just replaced `oDoc.Close` with `oDoc.CheckIn`

```
oDoc.Save
oDoc.CheckIn
oWord.Quit
```